# System modal MessageBoxW problems when right-click inside Solidworks application

Tags: vba, winapi, modal-dialog, solidworks

I've written a VBA 7.0 program which automates some things in Solidworks.  One of the things I have to do is check for typos in a few areas within the Solidworks document.  What I've done is use an API call to MessageBoxW to display a system modal message box so they have the opportunity to fix the typo before continuing, or cancel.

The messagebox displays fine, and I can go into the running Solidworks application and work within it, but when I right-click within the program and try to use the RMB context menu, some weird stuff starts happening.
1) The mouse buttons no longer work within the program or on the messagebox window.  Other application windows continue to respond just fine, but any mouse clicks (RMB or LMB) anywhere within the Solidworks application window or in the messagebox window do nothing. The windows are not frozen - I can hit escape key to exit the context menu and then everything works fine.  The mouse button clicks just seem to not register while the context menu is up.
2) The RMB context menu "becomes system modal".  I'm not sure if that's what is happening, but best way I could think to describe it.  Essentially the context menu will keep displayed on top of all other application windows.  I can still work within other windows though with no negative effects other than the context menu being in the way.

Not sure if this is an issue with Solidworks, the MessageBoxW function, or a combination of both.

EDIT: This happens ONLY while the message box is displayed, once that is closed behavior is normal.

I'm calling the API functions like this:

`lngReply=WinMsgBox(Prompt:="Can you do this thing for me? blah blah",Title:="Action required",Buttons:=vbOkCancel + vbInformation + vbSystemModal`

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function MessageBoxW Lib "User32" _
                                       (Optional ByVal hWnd As Long, _
                                        Optional ByVal Prompt As LongPtr, _
                                        Optional ByVal Title As LongPtr, _
                                        Optional ByVal Buttons As Long) _
                                    As Long


Public Function WinMsgBox(Optional ByRef hWnd As Long, _
                        Optional ByRef Prompt As String, _
                        Optional ByRef Title As String, _
                        Optional ByRef Buttons As Long) _
                    As Long

WinMsgBox = MessageBoxW(hWnd, StrPtr(Prompt), StrPtr(Title), Buttons)

End Function
```

Comment: Do you mean this happens while the message box is displayed or it persists after the dialog has been dismissed?

Comment: Good question - it happens ONLY while the message box is displayed, once that is closed behavior is normal.  I edited the original question with this info.

Comment: Well, a message box is modal and disables *all* windows.  So this is entirely expected.  The only real flaw is that the context menu didn't close yet.  It should have, probably an issue in the host program.

Comment: The message box runs its own modal message loop. If the Solidworks message loop is non-standard in any way (e.g. it may make use of posted thread messages, which aren't dispatched to a window) then this will stop working while another message loop is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like something that just can't work. A modal dialog box runs its own event loop, disables its parent and may capture the mouse. Trouble right down the line. I'm surprised it works as well as it does.

A better solution would be a non-modal dialog box or an app written as a dialog. You can make it 'on top' so it just sits there until they're ready to make it go away.

---

A non-modal dialog box is created with CreateDialog(). Something like this: http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/modeless_dialogs.html. And topmost is a style: WS_EX_TOPMOST. 
I can't help with turning that into VB.

Comment: Looking at the documentation for MessageBox function, it looks like the only options are Application Modal, System Modal, or Task Modal.  How would I create a modeless dialog box?  Create a userform programmatically and call using `.show vbModeless` or something like that? If so, how would I get it to sit on top then?

Comment: I'll look into CreateDialog() and see what I can do.